# Clarify xcode obj-c code

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is a simple one, it's just that I can't figure out what it means.

Is it 4 different methods or one method with 4 parameters.

```
+ (double)doCalc:(float)interestRate
                    numOfCompounds:(int)interestFrequency
                    intialDeposited:(float)deposit
                    lengthOfTimeBanked:(int)period;
```

What confuses me is where it comes out with numOfCompounds:(int)interestFrequency.

Does it means it's a separate parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one method with four parameters. The whitespace and line breaks are there only for readability.

The four parameters are:

1. `interestRate`, a float
2. `interestFrequency`, an int
3. `deposit`, a float
4. `period`, an int

The name of the method, without the parameter signatures, is actually

```
doCalc:numOfCompounds:intialDeposited:lengthOfTimeBanked:
```

In one of the parts of the signature, for example `numOfCompounds:(int)interestFrequency`, `numOfCompounds` is the name of the parameter as seen by the calling code, while `interestFrequency` is the name of the parameter in the scope of the method.

Comment: Thanks, have to say your answer is much more easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This is all one method. The method declaration doesn't end until the closing `;`.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what it means by the parameter being numOfCompounds:(int)interestFrequency. the colon confuses me. Thanks

Comment: This is a unique objective-C thing which can be confusing. The colon separates the description of a parameter with the actual parameter. A simple example to clarify would be a function -(void)DrawPointAtX:(int)x andY:(int)y; The function DrawPointAtX andY takes the integer parameters x and y. Hope this helps.

Comment: Named arguments are not unique to Objective-C but they are rare and rule like hell. They really make code document itself.